# Alamofire3 - Alamofire.download : responseArray return response nil

Tags: swift, alamofire

My code ******

```
let responseDownloaded =  Alamofire.download(.GET, url, destination: { (url, response) -> NSURL in

    let pathComponent = "recent.json"

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let fileUrl = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
    return fileUrl
})

responseDownloaded.responseArray(keyPath: "aTracks")  {[unowned self] (response: Response< [DataMusic], NSError>) in
    switch response.result {

    case .Success(let music):
        // some code
    case .Failure(let error):
        // some code
    }
}
```

---

File with json is downloaded to disk, but responseArray give me response nil. What is it wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire.download() is not returning any value.

If you need to access a response data:

```
Alamofire.download(
    url,
    method: .get,
    parameters: parameters,
    encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
    headers: nil,
    to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
        //progress closure
    }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
        //here you able to access the DefaultDownloadResponse
        //result closure
    })
```

Comment: It is Alamofire 4 or 3

Comment: It is Alamofire 4.0 using Swift 3. If you look for Alamofire 3.x solutions, please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

My solution (with ObjectMapper and SwiftyJSON) :

```
    var fileName: String?
    var finalPath: NSURL?

   Alamofire.download(.GET, url, destination: { (temporaryURL, response) in

        if let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as? NSURL {

            fileName = response.suggestedFilename!
            finalPath = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName!)
            return finalPath!
        }

        return temporaryURL
    })
        .response { (request, response, data, error) in

            var fileExist: Bool!

            let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            let filePath = url.URLByAppendingPathComponent("recent.json").path!
            let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
             fileExist = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(filePath) ? true : false

                if fileExist != nil {

                let jsonData = JSON(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))!)
                    if let aTracks = jsonData.dictionary {
                         if let track = aTracks["aTracks"] {

                             if let arrTack = Mapper<DataMusic>().mapArray(track.rawString()) {

                            }

                        }
                    }
            }


    }
```